# Check for truncated HTML entity with substr

Tags: php, character-encoding, preg-match, substr

If I have:

```
$output = substr($str, 0, 3);
```

and `$str` has value 'à àbcde'.
$output value will have value 'à &ag' with the `&agrave ;` being cut off. 
I want output to have value 'à àb'.

I tried `mb_substr($str, 0, 3, 'UTF-8')` same problem.
Using `html_entity_decode` on `$str` gave me 500 internal server error.
EDIT:
Ive noticed that the 500 error only happens if the part of string being truncated is a part of an html entity.

Comment: if you're dealing with encoded html, you'll have to DECODE back to plain text, then do your substring, then RE-encode. the string functions can NOT be expected to deal with html character entities.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the right encodings. `$str` might not be utf8. Only you know the encoding. PHP can guess, but not very surely.

Using `html_entity_decode()` is the way to go.

OR you have to do a count yourself:

```
$str = 'Hello &amp; byeye!';

// mb_ shouldn't be necessary because all mb chars are html encoded
$output = substr($str, 0, 8);
var_dump($output);
$cutoff = is_int($pos = strrpos($output, '&')) && strrpos($output, ';') < $pos;
if ( $cutoff ) {
  $output = substr($str, 0, 1+strpos($str, ';', strlen($output)));
  var_dump($output);
}
```

Something like that. But `html_entity_decode()` is better, so turn `error_reporting` and `display_errors` on and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to return an accentuated character, you have to convert your string to real UTF-8 characters (or whatever encoding you prefer), not `&agrave;` and the likes. Php treats all those as characters, there's no way you will get substr to recognize this whole `&agrave;` as a single character.

you can use

```
// $str = '&agrave; &agravecde'
html_entity_decode($str,ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8');
// $str = 'à àcde';
$output = substr($str, 0, 3);
// $output = 'à àc'
```

I know you've apparently tried html_entity_decode, but I'm pretty sure the function is not broken. Are there characters in your string that are already translated in any different encoding? please echo the string that did a problem with html_entity_decode?